# ASP.Net Core 2 authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am lost with authentification in ASP.Net Core 2 MVC Applications.
I am working with Core 2 version and it seems there are a lot of changes between version 1 and 2. I have read some tutorials which does not really works.

First of all, here is what i put in *Startup.cs* in `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUserClass, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDatabaseEFContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

and here is what i put in `Configure()` method:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

I put this annotation on each action method of each controller:

```
[Authorize]
```

And here is what i've done in my post action login method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Login)};
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PrivateController");
}
```

I get this exception when i try to login:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: Could be you are missing `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` as mentioned in docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity or just cookie authentication? Currently, your code is using both.

Answer (score 4):

In your `Configure()` method change `app.UseIdentity()` to:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**Also, note**: If you are using cookies without Identity (as it appears in your `Index` action):

> Invoke the `AddAuthentication` and `AddCookie` methods in the
>   `ConfigureServices` method:
>
> ```
> // If you don't want the cookie to be automatically authenticated and assigned to HttpContext.User, 
> // remove the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme parameter passed to AddAuthentication.
> services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
>         .AddCookie(options => 
>         {
>             options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
>             options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
>         });
> ```

Additional reading: [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

Comment: @Bob5421: if you are using cookies without Identity you will need to add `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` in your ConfigureServices. See updated answer and [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

Comment: In fact i do not understand the difference between cookies and identity. What i want is authentication with a session like in php :)

Comment: You should read this [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x). It is the line `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync` that is causing your problem. If you want to use Identity, you should use a `SignInManager.SignInAsync()` instead.

Comment: You are absolutely true. This was the problem. But i do not understand why HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync does not work !

Comment: It didn't work because you had not registered an authentication scheme with the name defined by `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` ("Cookies") in your `Startup`, so when you tried to sign in with that scheme, there was nothing to do but throw an exception. You can quite happily authenticate with any number of schemes (e.g. Identity, Basic Auth...), so long as you register them in startup with `AddAuthentication()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it the way I do my own Logout() action which deletes the authentication cookie and then redirects to the start page. To do it reliably I gave the auth. cookie my own name using the `ConfigureServices()` method in `Startup.cs`.

**Startup.cs:**

```
    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ..

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyOwnCookieName";
        });
        ...
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete("MyOwnCookieName");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Maybe this saves someone some time as I used a lot of time to get there.